# DHCP Post-Install configuration wizard hangs

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, dhcp-server

I'm attempting to set up a Windows 2012 Active Directory demo environment on a Hyper-V VM, but when I run the *DHCP Post-Install configuration wizard* to authorize the DHCP server in AD DS, the wizard hangs when I press Commit.

This is a Hyper-V VM, it should be hosting DHCP and DNS for the domain. It's connected to an "Internal" Hyper-V network switch.

What's causing the wizard to hang? How can I diagnose this? As far as I can tell, DHCP and DNS are configured correctly.

Alternatively: the DHCP server *is already* authorized in AD (presumably it succeeded). How do I get rid of the notification flag in Server Manager?

**Update:** After about 5 minutes, it finally failed with "Failed to open registry key on target computer to set the status of post configuration task. Error: The WinRM client received an HTTP status code of 504 from the remote WS-Management service."

This is a single-machine installation (and the firewall's disabled anyway), so what's going wrong here?

Comment: An `internal` Hyper-V Virtual Switch doesn't proffer connectivity to the physical network. You should be connecting this VM to an `external` virtual switch.

Comment: @joeqwerty irrelevant; this is all on the same box, and I don't _want_ it having access to the external network. Exposing a DHCP server that way is bad.

Comment: What? How would the DHCP server service clients if it weren't connected to the physical network? How could your DC service domain clients if it weren't connected to the physical network? Who said exposing a DHCP server to the physical network is bad? How else would it be able to service clients? I'm not talking about exposing it to a public network, I'm talking about exposing it to your LAN so that it can service LAN clients. That's how DHCP servers are implemented. The fact that it's a VM is irrelevant. A DHCP server needs to be connected to the network of the clients it's going to service.

Comment: In my question, it says "demo environment". By that I meant to imply that every machine in the demo will be virtualized, and will be on the internal switch. This, further, implies that I might be running it on a box connected to a production network. Allowing a demo DHCP server free reign on a production network is a big no-no.

Answer (score 2):

If the administrator has completed the post-install configuration using PowerShell, Server Manager may still raise a flag (alert) for its completion using the post-install configuration wizard. This alert can be suppressed by notifying the Server Manager that the post-install configuration has been completed. This can be done by the below command:

```
Set-ItemProperty –Path registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ServerManager\Roles\12 –Name ConfigurationState –Value 2
```

I actually unauthorized my scope, it fixed itself, and then I re-authorized it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more then 1 NIC in your server you must set the priority of the NIC you want to serve DHCP requests to be the first in the list. Also if you are not using the other NICs then disable them.

Unauthorise your DHCP scope then re run the Post Installation Configuration Wizard.

This also fixes the problem of your server name in DHCP showing as a 169, network address and not the nmae of your server.