# DHCP post-install configuration error

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp-server

Server 2012 R2

I moved my DHCP operation out of my Cisco router and into the server.  In this case I used the domain server as I have a small system.  DHCP seems to be working fine.

However, Server Manager keeps informing that post-install configuration needs to be performed, and when I try to do that, I get an error about a registry key.

There are a variety of posts on the net, this one in this forum, [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/497675/dhcp-post-install-configuration-wizard-hangs), though it is a couple of years old.  This [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/01802039-bf8b-4cfe-9dcc-5fdd0b3c4dfe/dhcp-post-install-error?forum=winserver8gen) shows the actual error message exactly as I have.  The graphic is almost to the end of the page.  Even after reading these I don't get the problem.

Is this still the solution?  To hack a registry key?  What is actually the problem in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my specific problem is actually included in the error message.

[image]

The last line suggests opening a command prompt and running:

```
winrm quickconfig
```

As soon as I did that, I re-ran the post-install configuration wizard, and this time after the authorization step there was no error.

I find this solution a better one than the various answers I found on the web that involved registry hacks.

I know, read the instructions is always a good idea...